# I am loosing focus on input while typing in React Hook

Tags: reactjs

When I am typing on the input then the focus loses after writing a single letter. I tried to follow [Input is loosing focus on hooks update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56758864/input-is-loosing-focus-on-hooks-update) but its still the same

Here is my code:

```js
// Input.js

export const DesktopSearch = ({Filter, SetFilter }) =>{
    return (
        <form>
            <div className="search_area">                
                <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Name" value={Filter.search} onChange={e => SetFilter({...Filter, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})}/>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}
```

```js
// App.js

export default function App() {

    const [Filter, SetFilter] = useState({search: ''})
    const Screens = () => {
    if(Screen === 1){
         return (<>
              <p>Screen 1</p>
              <DesktopSearch Filter={Filter} SetFilter={SetFilter}/>
         </>)
    }
    else(Screen === 2){
         return (<>
              <p>Screen 2</p>
              <DesktopSearch Filter={Filter} SetFilter={SetFilter}/>
         </>)
    }
    }
    return (
         <Screens/>
    )

}
```

Comment: Maybe just need an `e.preventDefault();` in your `onChange` handler (next to `SetFilter` call)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your "if ... else" is useless and should be reduced. Furthermore, you are rerendering your component `onChange`, you should apply the single responsibility principle and let your input manage its own state.

I would like to add that variable names should start with a lowercase character.

```
export default function App() {


    return (
         <>
              <p>Screen {Screen}</p>
              <DesktopSearch />
         </>
    );

}
```

Other file:

```
export const DesktopSearch = () =>{
    const [Filter, SetFilter] = useState({search: ''});

    return (
        <form>
            <div className="search_area">                
                <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Name" value={Filter.search} onChange={e => SetFilter({...Filter, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})}/>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Comment: I had to use if-else because I had to write more data representation which changes and the App.js has the main state because the whole axios function runs over there using useEffects.

Answer (score 0):

You are using your `Screens` function like a component, but it is just a method in your function component. Try to invoke it instead of using like a component:

```
export default function App() {
  const [Filter, SetFilter] = useState({ search: "" });
  const Screens = () => {
    if (Screen === 1) {
      return (
        <>
          <p>Screen 1</p>
          <DesktopSearch Filter={Filter} SetFilter={SetFilter} />
        </>
      );
    } else if (Screen === 2) {
      return (
        <>
          <p>Screen 2</p>
          <DesktopSearch Filter={Filter} SetFilter={SetFilter} />
        </>
      );
    }
  };

  return Screens();
}
```

or you can drop it totally:

```
export default function App() {
  const [Filter, SetFilter] = useState({ search: "" });
    if (Screen === 1) {
      return (
        <>
          <p>Screen 1</p>
          <DesktopSearch Filter={Filter} SetFilter={SetFilter} />
        </>
      );
    } else if (Screen === 2) {
      return (
        <>
          <p>Screen 2</p>
          <DesktopSearch Filter={Filter} SetFilter={SetFilter} />
        </>
      );
    }
}
```